# How to send down arrow keys for a drop down?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, browser-automation

```java
selenium.getDriver().findElement(By.id("s2id_customFilter")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Am using the above code but it's not working."s2id_customFilter" is the id of the drop down.Am clicking on the id and sending keys but there's no action from selenium.

My code:

```java
jQueryWebElement filterElement = selenium.jQuery("#s2id_customFilter");
selenium.jQuery(".select2-choice",filterElement).click();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "one");
selenium.getDriver().findElement(By.id("s2id_customFilter")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW‌​_DOWN);
```

Comment: Probably depends on where the focus is. If you put a call to `Click()` first, to make sure focus is on the drop-down list, does that make a difference?

Comment: I agree with @vincebowdren .  It sounds to me like a focus issue as well.

Comment: @vincebowdren ... No difference it's still not working.Yes i have mentioned a click() before the above code to click on drop-down.

Comment: @user5492 Can you show some more of your webdriver code, and screenshots of the control you're trying to interact with?

Comment: `jQueryWebElement filterElement = selenium.jQuery("#s2id_customFilter");
selenium.jQuery(".select2-choice",filterElement).click();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "one");
selenium.getDriver().findElement(By.id("s2id_customFilter")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);`

Comment: @selenium_vtiger If that's the solution you used to get the job done, perhaps you could craft a small post describing that, and then accept it as your solution? That'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ive got the same issue and reported here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1622.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the answer from the [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1622) Philip Beadle posted in a comment:

> It's a bad idea to test the core browser's behaviour as it's not your 
>   logic, i.e. you should not need to test that arrow keys work with
>   options since that's something your browser implements.

And some [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/) (JavaScript) examples how to handle the drop from the same link:

```
var options = element(by.id('s2id_customFilter'));
    options.sendKeys('textofyouroption')
```

And another one when the text changes a lot or is dynamic:

```
var optionsElements = element(by.id('s2id_customFilter')).all(by.tagName('option'));
    optionsElements.count().then(function(count) {
      console.log('I have ' + count + ' options')
    });
    optionsElements.get(1).click(); // click on 2nd option
```

You should be able to do something similar in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move cursor first. Did you try to use moveToElement(WebElement toElement) before clicking on it? [This link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

May wish to try the following (C# Selenium Dev Studio 2015 environment)

There is a drop down item on the page labelled Contact Person, I used firebug inside of Mozilla FireFox to get the absolute XPATH of this drop down item as depicted below

```
public static readonly string ContactPerson_DD_AXPATH = 
        "html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select";
```

Then in my C# code to cause a down arrow and enter keys functions on the drop down I code:

```
IWebElement contactName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(ContactPerson_DD_AXPATH));

contactName.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown+Keys.Enter+Keys.Escape);
```

I learned somewhere that sending an Escape may help some tough key sequence actions from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

For any rubyists, I've found 'pick first option in the dropdown' a powerful way to avoid data combinatorial testing through the UI, once you create unit and integrated tests that do that testing and explain that to the business.

As a method, e.g. selecting the first school from a test field dropdown

```
def select_first_school select_id
  find_by_id(select_id).send_keys :arrow_down
  find_by_id(select_id).send_keys :tab
end
```